# My javascript works only sometimes on webhosting

Tags: javascript, html, web-hosting

I have a problem with my javascript. It is a gallery slider.  It works perfectly on localhost, but when i upload it on webhosting it works only sometimes, after many refreshes. Console does not write any errors and everything seems completely fine.

```js
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide img');
 
//Buttons
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

//Counter   
 let counter = 1;
 const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

 carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX('+ (-size * counter) +'px)';
 

 //Button Listeners
 nextBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
     if (counter>= carouselImages.length -1) {return;}
     carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.7s ease-in-out";
     counter++
     carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX('+ (-size * counter) +'px)';


 });

 prevBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if (counter <=0) {return;}
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.7s ease-in-out";
    counter--
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX('+ (-size * counter) +'px)';


});
carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', ()=> {

    if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'lastClone')
    {
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - 2;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX('+ (-size * counter) +'px)';

    }
    if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone')
    {
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - counter;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX('+ (-size * counter) +'px)';

    }

});
```

Comment: When is the code shown run?

Comment: The debugger is your friend. Set a breakpoint and follow the code flow. You can even start Chrome with `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` to immediately open dev tools and enable the debugger and network monitor.

Comment: Check does files loaded (js, css...)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your current code breaks with error: `TypeError: carouselImages[0] is undefined`

Comment: Did you check in incognito mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

page load speed is the first thing that comes to mind.
running on localhost is usually super fast. and the DOM is loaded before your code is executed.

without further information about WHEN is your code executed ? i can not be precise .

But i think different refreshes has a relation. try attaching a debugger (you can do it with Chrome debugger) and check the values of your variables.

Double check if your code is running after the Document is ready.

Comment: Thanks, that help a lot.